# Why while being in a local branch can't I pull into a local branch from another local branch with no potential for merge conflict? "No match"

Tags: magit

See the picture below:

[image]

I am in a branch called `430-toggle-hide-show-colums` (in green).

This is a local branch pushed to GitHub as P.R. draft (not yet merged).

Accidentally, I ended up doing development on the wrong branch `back-up-pode-te-salvar` which was supposed to be a "back-up" branch before doing some interactive rebase changes.

I would like to bring the fast forward changes from `back-up-pode-te-salvar` which has a few commits in the future (all other parts are equal) into the official green branch called `430-toggle-hide-show-column`.

Being on `430-toggle-hide-show-column`, I tried the following:

1 - I pressed `F` (`magit-pull`)

2 - After being asked:

> Pull into 430-toggle-hide-show-columns from

I pressed `e` from `elsewhere`

3 - And then typed

```
Pull: back-up-pode-te-salvar-430
```

It was necessary to type everything since auto-complete did not work as I was expecting.

Worse than that, the mini-buffer echoed: `No match`.

There is no potential conflict.

Why is this happening?

How can I pull changes from one local branch to another in Magit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but, apparently, the solution is executing command `magit-merge` which is bound to `m` in my config, and then executing `m` again which is associated with the `merge` flag. There are other options, such as `squash-and-merge`. But, `merge` seems the best for my situation.

Also, I still do not understand why `pull` did not work, specially since `merge` is part of `pull`, as far as I know.

Comment: A git "pull" is the combination of its "fetch" and "merge" commands, and it performs both of those actions for the argument you give it.  You weren't fetching anything.  In short, if you're not wanting to fetch, pull is the wrong command.